# Calculate Final outcome based on Results/ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, subquery, window-functions

For a Table T1

```
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| PersonID |   Date    |   Employment    |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
|        1 | 2/28/2017 | Stayed the same |
|        1 | 4/21/2017 | Stayed the same |
|        1 | 5/18/2017 | Stayed the same |
|        2 | 3/7/2017  | Improved        |
|        2 | 4/1/2017  | Stayed the same |
|        2 | 6/1/2017  | Stayed the same |
|        3 | 3/28/2016 | Improved        |
|        3 | 5/4/2016  | Improved        |
|        3 | 4/19/2017 | Worsened        |
|        4 | 5/19/2016 | Worsened        |
|        4 | 2/16/2017 | Improved        |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

I'm trying to calculate a `Final Result` field partitioning on Employment/PersonID fields, based on the latest result/person relative to prior results. What I mean by that is explained in the logic behind `Final Result`:

For every Person,

1. If all results/person are Stayed the same, then only should final
   result for that person be "Stayed the same"
2. If Worsened/Improved
   are in the result set for a person, the final result should be the
   latest Worsened/Improved result for that person, irrespective of "Stayed the same" after a W/I result.

Eg:

- Person 1 Final result -> Stayed the same, as per (1)
- Person 2 Final result -> Improved, as per (2)
- Person 3 Final result -> Worsened, as per (2)
- Person 4 Final result -> Improved, as per (2)

**Desired Result:**

```
+----------+-----------------+
| PersonID |  Final Result   |
+----------+-----------------+
|        1 | Stayed the same |
|        2 | Improved        |
|        3 | Worsened        |
|        4 | Improved        |
+----------+-----------------+
```

I know this might involve Window functions or Sub-queries but I'm struggling to code this.

Comment: partitioned row_number() will get you what you want with a case expression or IIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  This is a prioritization query.  That sounds like `row_number()` is called for:

```
select t1.personid, t1.employment
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by personid
                                order by (case when employment <> 'Stayed the same' then 1 else 2 end),
                                         date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Would this also work if I added another field similar to Employment to  calculate a related `Final Result 2` field?

Comment: @AS91 . . . If you have another question, then ask it as *another* question rather than in a comment.  Don't change a question once it has already been answered -- that can invalidate an answer and attract downvotes.

Comment: I thought I'd reach a trade-off between simplifying a problem and replicating the result at a higher level at the cost of losing complexity in question. Sequencing the results based on a particular field obviously changes that. So I'll try going with this and get back to you. Thank you.