# Calculate final outcomes based on Results/ID for multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, window, subquery

Extending the solution for this: [Calculate Final outcome based on Results/ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663201/calculate-final-outcome-based-on-results-id/44663244?noredirect=1#comment76312270_44663244)

Using the same business logic, how can I obtain another `Final Result 2` based on the `LA` field alongside `Final Result` based on `Employment` field? The ranking function would obviously work different when more than one field is involved.

Table T1 extended:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| PersonID |   Date    |   Employment    |       LA        |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|        1 | 2/28/2017 | Stayed the same | Improved        |
|        1 | 4/21/2017 | Stayed the same | Stayed the same |
|        1 | 5/18/2017 | Stayed the same | Improved        |
|        2 | 3/7/2017  | Improved        | Stayed the same |
|        2 | 4/1/2017  | Stayed the same | Stayed the same |
|        2 | 6/1/2017  | Stayed the same | Improved        |
|        3 | 3/28/2016 | Improved        | Improved        |
|        3 | 5/4/2016  | Improved        | Improved        |
|        3 | 4/19/2017 | Worsened        | Worsened        |
|        4 | 5/19/2016 | Worsened        | Stayed the same |
|        4 | 2/16/2017 | Improved        | Stayed the same |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

**Desired Output:**

```
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| PersonID |  Final Result   | Final Result 2  |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|        1 | Stayed the same | Improved        |
|        2 | Improved        | Improved        |
|        3 | Worsened        | Worsened        |
|        4 | Improved        | Stayed the same |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Perhaps a better table design would help.  Rather than storing the values as VarChar, have them as integers and a table where you can lookup the text.  With the integers you could then use Min() or Max() to find the values you desire.

Comment: @vkp As I mentioned in the original thread, the same business logic as `Final Result` for `Final Result 2`. i.e. If Stayed the same throughout per person, then Stayed the same. If Worsened/Improved, then latest W/I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another RN should work

```
select t1.personid, t1.employment, t2.LA
from (select t1.*,
                row_number() over (partition by personid
                                order by (case when employment <> 'Stayed the same' then 1 else 2 end),
                                            date desc
                                ) as seqnum
        from t1
        ) t1
left join
    (select t1.PersonID, t1.LA,
                row_number() over (partition by personid
                                order by (case when LA <> 'Stayed the same' then 1 else 2 end),
                                            date desc
                                ) as seqnum
        from t1) t2 on t2.PersonID = t1.PersonID and t2.seqnum = 1
where t1.seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Could you please explain the ordinals in the CASE statement for the ORDER BY clause? Which fields do they refer to and why ordinals? Why not field names directly here? If I understand correctly, 1 is personid and 2 is Date. But using the field names directly gives various data type errors.

Comment: i took the same logic as gordon which you accepted which applies a 1 to anything that isn't 'Stayed the same' Looking back, it should probably be = instead of <> but I went with the same logic since you accepted it. The difference is i'm looking at LA instead of employment. Where are you getting an error?

Comment: The logic used in CASE does get the desired result with <>. In the same query, if I replace 1 and 2 with `PersonID` and `Date` in the ORDER BY, I get `Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date` error. Aren't the ordinals and actual field names the same thing? Also, if Result= W/I, then it'll first order by Date Ascending and then Date Descending. That doesn't make sense. And Ordering by 1 shouldn't make a difference since they're all the same ID's in each partition. What am I missing?

Comment: You can't have the result of a case statement be two different data types. You could cast both to varchar but then your order by wouldn't order correctly as the int would be ordered as 1, 10, 101, 2, 20 etc for example as would your dates. Basically they'd use the Unicode values. The DESC only applies to the date sort not the case statement

Comment: But somehow the ordinals for the same fields does the trick? I thought the ordinals would ultimately translate to the same data type differences

Comment: No we are forcing an INT based on the values of the column for the case statement thus returning only 1 or 2. It's called conditional sorting and is pretty common for cases like this. For example, say I wanted to sort on lastName and make smith first and the rest alphabetical I'd use a case and assign smith 1 else lastName. SQL would automatically convert 1 to varchar and sort but Unicode 1 comes before all letters so it's fine

Comment: Just remove the seqnum = 1 and add the seqnum to your outer select and look at what it does